# How would be the best way to chain ajax calls (one ajax call fire another one)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, chaining

I am trying to chain ajax calls: when i load html content in all element i want load it in others. I would want to do without hardcode the calls in each element with closures attached to the local ajax events.
I tried to do with global ajax events like so:

```
$("#elem2").ajaxSuccess(function(e,x,opts) {
  var myUrl="server/elem2"
  if(conditionToAvoidRecursiveCalls)
    $(this).load(myUrl)
})
```

but i dont get how to define the conditionToAvoidRecursiveCalls: e.target!=this dont work and opts.url!==url dont avoid mutually recursive calls.

Is there another clever way?

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand what you're trying to do, but hearing "chaining ajax calls" makes me want to ask you, if you had a look at jQuery's `queue()` method: http://api.jquery.com/queue/ ?

Comment: jumm im afraid i have not been clear, the "chain" is only between a ajax call and some others ones which have to be called "by default", f.e. load a tab via ajax have to fire reloading breadcrumbs in the page. I think i have no problem with race conditions or the order of calls. Thanks for the reference to that plugin anyway, it's neat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution was simpler than i thougth, there is a option in ajax call which already do what i want (global:false):

```
var html=$.ajax({url: url,global:false}).responseText
$(this).html(html)
```

> global Boolean Default: true
>
> Whether to trigger global Ajax event
>   handlers for this request. The default
>   is true. Set to false to prevent the
>   global handlers like ajaxStart or
>   ajaxStop from being triggered. This
>   can be used to control various Ajax
>   Events.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Ajax Queue**](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxqueue) plugin. It's written by John Resig himself.